# Count from json decode always show different number of sum

Tags: php, html, json, codeigniter

I'm new to use API. I have a problem in counting the data and display it to html view. I'm using count($data) to count it in html view, but the result is different if I compare it to the data.Here's my data I get from API. I only show 9 sample data here. Here are the data I get from API.

```
   {"rows":[{"ID":26,"Name":"Design Request (Draft)"}, 
   {"ID":25,"Name":"Kirim Produk Iklan"},
   {"ID":27,"Name":"Kirim Produk Iklan Reguler"},
   {"ID":18,"Name":"KMP - Advertorial"},
   {"ID":34,"Name":"KMP - Advertorial Daerah"},
   {"ID":5,"Name":"KMP - Artikel"},
   {"ID":9,"Name":"KMP - Artikel Editor"},
   {"ID":28,"Name":"KMP - Artikel PB"},
   {"ID":29,"Name":"KMP - Desain Grafis"},
 "status":0,"message":"","messagedescription":"","rowcount":9,"columns":["ID","Name"]}
```

here's my controller

```
    function index(){

    $output = $this->http_request('http://api.com');
    $profile = json_decode($output, TRUE);
    $config['total_rows'] = count($profile);
    var_dump($config);
    $data['data']=$profile;
    $data['sidebar']='sidebar';
    $data['content']='apinew';
    $this->load->view('main',$data);

}

function http_request($url){


    // persiapkan curl
    $ch = curl_init(); 

    // set url 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    // set user agent    
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');

    // return the transfer as a string 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

    // $output contains the output string 
    $output = curl_exec($ch); 

    // tutup curl 
    curl_close($ch);      

    // mengembalikan hasil curl
    return $output;
}
```

here's my view

```
      <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
         <tr>
          <th class="text-center" scope="col"> ID </th>
          <th class="text-center" scope="col">Job</th>
          <th class="text-center" scope="col">Action</th><!-- 
          <th class="text-center">Actions</th> -->
         </tr>
       </thead>
        <tbody>
           <?php for($i =0 ; $i < count($data); $i++){ ?>
           <tr>
            <td class="align-middle text-center"><?php echo $data['rows'][($i)]['ID'];?></td>
            <td class="align-middle text-center"><?php echo $data['rows'][($i)]['Name'] ?></td>
            <td class="text-center align-middle">
            <div class="btn-group align-top">
           <a onclick="window.location.href='<?php echo base_url('apinew/edit/'.$data['rows'][$i]['Name']);?>'" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary badge">Edit</a>
            </div></td>
           </tr>
           <?php } ?>
          </tbody>
  </table>
```

Thank You :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are counting the `data` variable, which contains the keys `rows`, `status`, `message` etc.

What you are actually looking for is the count of `$data['rows']`, so you could fix your code by switching it to count the correct field.

```php
$i =0 ; $i < count($data); $i++)
// change to
$i =0 ; $i < count($data['rows']); $i++)
```

You should, however use a `foreach` rather than a for loop for iterating over an array, like below. This saves you having to determine the index every iteration, and gives you direct access to each row.

```php
<?php foreach ($data['rows'] as $row) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td class="align-middle text-center"><?php echo $row['ID']; ?></td>
        <td class="align-middle text-center"><?php echo $row['Name'] ?></td>
        <td class="text-center align-middle">
            <div class="btn-group align-top">
                <a onclick="window.location.href='<?php echo base_url('apinew/edit/' . $row['Name']); ?>'"
                   class="btn btn-sm btn-primary badge">Edit</a>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```